# Is there any specific reason why the speaker here said 'our moment of education'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

> The right to know, the power to act, the will to love -- that is what I think my kids would ask of you if they were here, welcoming you to the world ahead. **It is true of our moment of education;** it is true of America's story.

It's a convocation speech at Harvard. 
And I want to ask if there's any reason why the speaker said 'our moment of education', instead of just 'education'.
Is he emphasizing the 'current' education or is it ok to just understand that as 'education'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the context, while he says "It is true of our **moment of** education", simply he is talking about the current education and emphasizing it in order to make it clear.

If he mentioned education without mention of the **moment**, then it could be -but not necessarily- that he meant to the education that he got 40 or 50 years ago ('our education'). Probably that's why he chose to make it clearer.